# DragResize library

Tags: javascript

I am using the DragResize plugin by Twin Helix organization. I have already posted query regarding its clash with the scrolling of outer container. Now I am facing a different issue.

The demo provided by the site has a single drag resize object which is applied to the document object. This causes all the divs within the document to show handles and allows resizing. My code requires a new dragresize object created every time an event happens. For example when I click a button, I draw a div and apply a new dragresize to it. This enables the div to get re sized. I have implemented the drag start method.

When I click on the button multiple times, though i am assigning null to the dragresize variable i can see that the start handler getting called that many times. I expect that everytime I click the button the previous reference in the dragresize variable is removed and the new object is assigned. But I am seeing that dragresize objects become a sort of array and if I start dragging on the latest one all the previous objects start handlers get called!!!

I think this could be a problem with garbage collection of javascript variable used. I am removing the div to which the dragresize object gets applied to, everytime confirmed by alerting the div before the apply code gets called. 
Please help me if you can,
Thanks
kavita

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating and applying Dragresize only once throughout the code and only changed the contents of the parent div to which it is applied.

Means everytime I click on the button my parent div contains a different div. The Dragresize object is the same and it gets applied to the same parent div. So There is no ambiguity and always the drag start method is invoked only once!!

Kavita